# distance between closed and compact set

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

my professor gave us this excercise:

The distance of two subsets $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ of a given complete metric space $(X, d)$ :
$$ d\left(S_{1}, S_{2}\right)=\inf \left\{d(x, y): x \in S_{1}, y \in S_{2}\right\}.$$

a) Suppose $S_{1}$ contains only one point $x$ and $S_{2}$ is closed. Prove $d\left(S_{1}, S_{2}\right)=d(x, y)$ for some $y \in S_{2}$.

b) Suppose $S_{1}$ is compact and $S_{2}$ is closed. Prove $d\left(S_{1}, S_{2}\right)=d(x, y)$ for some $x \in S_{1}$ $y \in S_{2}$.

I managed to do the first item (using a Cauchy sequence and the fact that X is a metric space), but the second one is giving me some problems, first I tried to use sequences but I did't go anywhere, I also though about seeing $d$ as a continous function in the product space, but a compact x closed is not compact, so I can't ensure that I get the minimum. Any idea would help. Thanks.

EDIT: My proof of a) If $S_1 \cap S_2 \neq \varnothing$ there is nothing to prove. If $S_1=\{x\}$,  let us suppose that $S_1 \cap S_2 = \varnothing$, then we can consider $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence such that $y_n \in S_2$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and such that $d(x,y_j)\leq d(x,y_i)$ if $i<j$. Clearly $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, therefore it converges to a $y \in S_2$ (due to the fact that $S_2$ is closed and therefore it contains all its accumulation points).

Comment: hint: convergent subsequences :)

Comment: @bof I already edit the question with a)

Comment: (a) is still false and so is (b).

Comment: Please tell me where I am wrong, what I understand is that $|y_n - y_m| \to 0 $ as it is defined, isn't?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez You don't even have to go to a weird space to find a counterexample to that.  For instance, $$X = \mathbb{R}^2\\ S_1 = \{(0,0)\},\qquad S_2 = \{x \in X : \|x\| \geq 1\}$$  Then just take a sequence $y_i$ such that $\|y_i\| = 1+\frac{1}{i}$ and with generic polar angles.  Obviously $y_i$ itself isn't a Cauchy sequence (we can extract one in this case by a compactness argument, but I believe bof's argument is effectively that we cannot even extract a Cauchy sequence in general)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see it there. I think you are right, is there a (not so weird) space where i can find a counter-example? i.e, where I can't find a cauchy sequence?

Comment: I think you may need a space that’s complete but not locally compact. Our intuition is based on $\Bbb R^n$, which is locally compact.

Comment: Ok, now I got it, thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Lubin, locally compact is not enough.  The counter example given by bof below is loc compact if you take $X$ to be $S_2\cup\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to (a) and therefore also to (b).

Let $X$ be the set of all nonnegative integers. Define a metric $d$ on $X$ by setting $d(x,x)=0$, $d(0,x)=d(x,0)=1+\frac1x$ for $x\gt0$, and $d(x,y)=2$ for $x,y\gt0$.

The metric space $(X,d)$ is complete (every Cauchy sequence is eventually constant) and locally compact (the induced topology is discrete).

Let $S_1=\{0\}$ and $S_2=X\setminus\{0\}$. Then $d(S_1,S_2)=d(0,S_2)=1$ but $d(0,y)\gt1$ for every $y\in S_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false in general. See the counterexample in the comments However, it is true if $X$ is a Topological Vector Space in which closed balls are compact. i.e if $X$ has what are called "nice closed balls":

for each integer $n$ there is a pair $(x_n,y_n)\in S_1\times S_2$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<d(S_1,S_2)+1/n$. Since $d(x_n,y_n)\ge d(S_1,S_2)$ this means that $d(s_n,y_n)\to d(S_1,S_2)$.  Since $S_1$ is compact there is a subsequence $(x'_n)$, of $(x_n),$ that converges to some $x\in S_1$. That is, $x'_n\to x\in S_1$. Note that in particular this means that $(x'_n)$ is bounded so $d(y'_n,0)\le d(y'_n,x'_n)+d(x'_n,0)<C<\infty.$ Thus, the closed ball $B_{2C}(0)$ is compact and contains $(y'_n)$, so we get a subsequence $(y''_n$) of $(y'_n)$ that converges to some $y\in B\cap S_2$ (because $S_2$ is closed).Then, of course, $x''_n$ still converges to $x$ and so $(x,y)$ is the pair that does the job.

Comment: Given the level of the question. I'm not sure the  OP would understand your Hilbert Space counterexample. But, no worries. I will gladly delete my answer. Although I believe it is correct.

Comment: The Hilbert space example was just a quick comment, I provided a simple ad hoc example in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it. Happy to upvote it. I wonder why my answer has been downvoted though.

Comment: I think your suggestion is fine. As for the downvotes, I only wish they would leave a comment, as you did, to make the proof better or to correct it if it is wrong.